# Will they renew my Aufenthaltstitel of my passport expires on the same day?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, us-citizens

Aufenthaltstitel (German Residence permit) I expiring the same day as my passport. I was wondering if they would deny my new application for Aufenthaltstitel if my passport expires the day I get it renewed. The Residence permit expires on the 4th of April and my passport does also. I am allowed to have the permit because I am married and my wife is German.

If you have any question please put a comment and please dont close this without commenting so I can make the question better.

Answer (score 1):

They may. Or may not. You will not know until you try. The safe way is to just get a new passport and renew your residence permit using *that*. There's plenty of time to do it, there's no point in not doing it and then going to the *Amt* in April and take a random chance of how forgiving the person you meet is going to be on that day.

Comment: I do not know if i can renew my passport in time, that's why i'm asking this question. I know i have to renew my passport. I was just asking if it works with a expired passport or a passport that is getting ready to expire

Comment: Then start on renewing like yesterday. Your card from the German Amt is no valid ID (although it looks like it) you need a valid Id to accompany the Aufenthaltsgenehmigung at all times.

Comment: I know that. I did asked them about the passport and they said all i need to do is show proof that i applied for a new one. I need to do a couple things still before I can send it, or else I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: If they already told you, I really don’t know what you expect to gain from answers here.

Comment: I asked today lol :) sorry I did forget to mention that. But I really appreciate the help and your answer! :)